# OpenCV: How to save a video with lossless compression

Tags: java, opencv3.1

I am using OpenCV 3.1 and I am trying to save a video with lossless compression, so that I don't get any RGB values changed. Currently I tried it with the avi container. Codecs I used were CorePNG (PNG1) and Motion PNG (MPNG), problem is that the Encoder can't be found. What do I have to install or consider to use those codecs properly and as I wanted? Are there any better codecs?

Comment: Have you built OpenCV with ffmpeg/gstreamer? Try installing ffmpeg and gstreamer, and compiling OpenCV with both frameworks. Codecs should be found if you do it properly.

Comment: No, I haven't used it till now. I would try it out but after downloading the files it get me anywhere. Could you tell me how to use this with eclipse?

Comment: I haven't worked with OpenCV Java in Eclipse, but as I said, first thing is to ensure that you have at least ffmpeg downloaded and included in your OpenCV built (don't use pre-built copies of OpenCV). Then you can follow this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d0a/tutorial_java_eclipse.html#gsc.tab=0) to use OpenCV with Eclipse.